# How to loop through rows and columns in a DatagridView to insert their values in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Well, I have a bunch of .txt files that I'm importing in a `DataGridView` with vb.net, these files will always have different columns, just like these two examples:

First and Second DataGridView
[image]

And I'm using the next code to loop through the rows and columns of the DataGridView and also the code insert the data to a mysql table, now, the process I make, it's the next:

- I open the .txt file.
- I tried to insert the data with the First DataGridView, but with the error, the data it's not supposed to be inserted to the table, nevertheless it does it, and although it only has 4 colummns, when I check my database, it shows everything messed up, and it duplicates columns, like the lower image.
- And then I "export" them to the mysql table. And when I do that, I get the error in the upper image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uGMQ.jpg]

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub ExportarToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportarToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=chafa;port=3306")
    conn.Open()

    Dim comm As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand()
    comm.Connection = conn

   

    Dim col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
       
    Dim tabla As New DataTable


    For i = 2 To DgvDatos.Rows.Add - 1 Step 1
        For j = 0 To Me.DgvDatos.Columns.Count - 1

            col1 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col2 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col3 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col4 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col5 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col6 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col7 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col8 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col9 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()
            col10 = DgvDatos.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value()


            comm.CommandText = "insert into ejemplo(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10) values('" & col1 &_ "','" & col2 & "','" & col3 & "','" & col4 & "','" & col5 & "','" & col6 & "','" & col7 & "','" & col8 & "','" & col9 & "','" & col10 & "')"
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Next



    MessageBox.Show("Datos Agregados Correctamente")
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First: you don't need to loop over the columns (this produces duplicates) Second: Learn how to use a parameterized query

Comment: Use a DataTable as the DataSource and just add rows to the datatable.  Whenever possible, work with the data not the user's view of it.

Comment: Create a `MySqlDataAdapter` using a `SELECT` command and a connection. Then using a `MySqlCommandBuilder` create `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` command automatically.  Put data in the `DataTable` and if you need to manipulate them, set the `DataTable` as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`. To save changes, call `Update` method of table adapter.

Comment: Apparently these are imported into the DGV prior to exporting to MySQL.  Does the user have to do something with these first?  If not you could just directly import them to MySQL

Comment: Well, actually I'm looking for a process to create the MySQL table from the data of the .txt files, (actually they are .csv), reading the second row, and using it as the headers ot each column, but they're always different, they can go from 50 columns, to 500, so, if you can tell me how to process them, before I can use  "LOAD DATA INFILE" or someting like that, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using sql not mysql but maybe it can help you:

```
query = String.Empty
        query &= "UPDATE schedule SET Task = @Task, Complete = @Complete, Start_date = @Start_date, "
        query &= "Due_date = @Due_date, JRID = @JRID, Task_Manager = @Task_Manager, Entered_By = @Entered_By, Time_Entered = @Time_Entered "
        query &= "WHERE TaskID = @TaskID "
        query &= "IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO schedule ( TaskID, Task, start_date, Due_Date, Complete, Task_Manager, JRID, Entered_By, Time_Entered)"
        query &= " VALUES ( @TaskID, @Task, @start_date, @Due_Date, @Complete, @Task_Manager, @JRID, @Entered_By, @Time_Entered);"
        If MainSchedule.isokclicked = 1 Then
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MainSchedule.DataGridView1.Rows
                If Not (row.Cells(0).Value = Nothing) Then
                    insertcommand.Parameters.Clear()
                    insertcommand.CommandText = query
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", row.Cells(0).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Complete", "False")
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task", row.Cells(1).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_date", row.Cells(2).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Due_Date", row.Cells(3).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JRID", txtJRID.Text)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task_Manager", row.Cells(4).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entered_By", GetUserName())
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time_Entered", Now)
                    insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
                keypos = keypos + 1
            Next
            Connexion.Close()
        Else
        End If
```

Its just a basic FOR loop that runs parameterized queries, it may not be the most efficient way, but it is simple. This code will also update the datatable, or insert if there is no matching key in the current database. Please don't hesitate to let me know if you have any questions, or even suggestions about/for my code.